# Android how to update value of ProgressBar?

Tags: android, progress-bar

My activity have a ProgressBar. When start activity, I'll check value get from another place and update to ProgressBar. Here's my code:

```
final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar_detail);
final TextView progressText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.progressText_detail);
final ImageView btnCancel = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgCancel_detail);
progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
progressText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
btnCancel.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                int oldProgress = 0;
                while (progressBar.getProgress() < 100) {
                    int value = Downloader.progress.get(gameId+ "");
                    if (value != oldProgress) {
                        oldProgress = value;
                        progressBar.setProgress(value);
                        progressText.setText(value + " %");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
t.start();
```

Value of ProgressBar i get from `int value = Downloader.progress.get(gameId)` and it's correct. But when I run this code, the activity is not responding and not showing anything (but app not crash). Seems like the thread to update ProgressBar running and block the UI thread so the activity layout is not showing.

What's wrong with my code? What is the correct way to update ProgressBar in this situation?

Comment: Try using AsyncTask, like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339847/how-to-add-progressdialog/11339895#11339895

Comment: [see this tuts](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html)

Comment: if you really wana use threads try to Thread.setPriority(NORMAL-1); otherwise  use AsyncTasks, they are pretty usefull.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are running a `while (progressBar.getProgress() < 100)` in the UI thread (you use `runOnUiThread`) so UI thread will be blocked (and nothing painted) until this loop finish.

You can:

- Put the `runOnUiThread` inside the loop and, maybe, a sleep inside de `runOnUiThread` call. However, it is not the preferred kind of solution since you are using too much CPU to just look for a value change. The sleep approach it a bit ugly but solves the cpu problem. It would be something like::

  ```
  Thread t = new Thread() {
      public void run() {
      int oldProgress = 0;

      while (progressBar.getProgress() < 100) {
              ((Activity) ctx).runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                  public void run() {
                      int value = Downloader.progress.get(gameId+ "");
                      if (value != oldProgress) {
                          oldProgress = value;
                          progressBar.setProgress(value);
                          progressText.setText(value + " %");
                      }
                  }
              }
              Thread.sleep(500);
          }
      });
    }
  };
  ```
- Update the progress bar in an event way so you only call (in the UI thread) the update code when progress changes. It is the preferred way.

Comment: How to Update the progress bar in a event way? Would you please be more specific?

Comment: Thank you. You're right about the loop inside UI thread. You also right about using too much CPU since my app run super slow. Can you tell me how to update the progress bar in a event way?

Comment: Not sure what Downloader does. It may have a ondownload event (or something similar) where you can submit a listener which do de update to the progressBar. If there weren't, you can take the a nit ugly sleep approach. Let me edit my answer to put a sample of if

Answer (score 2):

Try with:

```
    int currentPosition=0;
    int total=mediaPlayer.getDuration();
    while(mediaPlayer!=null && currentPosition<total){
        try{
            if(progressEnable){
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                currentPosition=mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                long pos=1000L * currentPosition/total;
                Log.d("thread pos", pos+"");
                progressSeekBar.setProgress((int) pos);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Declare progressEnable globally:

```
private boolean progressEnable=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this code:

```
private int mProgressStatus;
private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

public void startProgress(View view) {
    final ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.horizontal_progress);
    mProgressStatus = 0;
    progressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);

    //progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(final Void... params) {
            while (mProgressStatus < 100) {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                mProgressStatus += 15;
                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        progressBar.setProgress(mProgressStatus);
                    }
                });
            }
            return null;
        }

    }.execute();
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You can auto-advance progress bar using RXJava.

```
@Override
protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    if (autoProgress) {
        autoProgressSubscriber = Observable.interval(0, 1000/60, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS) //~60fps
                    .map(index -> calculateAutoProgress())
                    .subscribe(progress -> {
                        if (progressBar != null) {
                            progressBar.setProgress(progress);
                        }
                    });
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
    if (autoProgress) {
        autoProgressSubscriber.unsubscribe();
    }
    super.onDetachedFromWindow();
}
```