# How to show a ProgressDialog using intent in Android?

Tags: android, android-intent, progressdialog

I have an Activity which downloads the data from the Database. While the Activity is doing this work, I want to show the progress with **ProgressDialog**.I use `ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL` because I want to show the actual values. I use a `Handler` to start the Activity which displays the **ProgressDialog**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ProgressDialogActivity.class);

private Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if(msg.what == SET_PROGRESS){


                intent.putExtra("action", "show");
                intent.putExtra("progress", msg.arg1);
                intent.putExtra("max", msg.arg2);
                intent.putExtra("message", syncMessage);
                intent.putExtra("title", R.string.please_wait);

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                startActivity(intent);
            }
            else if(msg.what == SHOW_PROGRESS){             


                intent.putExtra("action", "show");
                intent.putExtra("title", syncMessage);

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                startActivity(intent);              
            }
            else if(msg.what == HIDE_PROGRESS){


                intent.putExtra("action", "hide");
                intent.putExtra("message", "");
                intent.putExtra("title", "");

                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                startActivity(intent);

            }
        }
    };
```

Here is the **ProgressDialogActivity**:

```
    public class ScreenProgressDialog extends Activity {

    ProgressDialog pd;
    Bundle extras;
    String action;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        extras = getIntent().getExtras();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);

        pd.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        pd.setCancelable(false);

        pd.setProgress(extras.getInt("progress"));  
        pd.setMax(extras.getInt("max"));
        pd.setMessage(extras.getCharSequence("message"));
        pd.setTitle(extras.getString("title"));

        action = extras.getString("action");

        if (action.equals("show")){
            pd.show();                  
        }
        else{
            pd.dismiss();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

}
```

When the Main Activity downloads a new table from the Database the `Handler` starts a new **ProgressDialogActivity** and a new Activity appears. I would like to avoid this. My aim is to show only ONE Activity which displays the **ProgressDialog** with the correct values. 
(I cannot create a **ProgressDialog** in the Main Activity, I have to find another way. It's some kind of homework but I need some help).
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) to fetch data in background and show **ProgressDialog**
Here is code:

```
// Get feed!
new ProgressTask().execute();



private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            /**
             * Fetch the RSS Feeds from URL
             */
            Utilities.arrayRSS = objRSSFeed
                    .FetchRSSFeeds(Constants.Feed_URL);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (success) {
            // display UI
            UpdateDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What about using an [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html): [How to add ProgressDialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339847/how-to-add-progressdialog/11339895#11339895)
Where you can do the download part in the `doInBackground` method and update the progress bar accordingly using `onProgressUpdate`..

Comment: Why do you have to use intents? You really should use a AsyncTask and Progress dialog to do something like this.  Right now you are trying starting a new activity every time you want to update a simple dialog.   Also you want to dismiss your dialog in the onPause() method of the activity, otherwise you can leak a window..