# Using ProgressDialog in asynctasks pre/post execute methods

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Edit: Problem solved. Make it global. I'm doing a facepalm right now guys. Thanks!

Below are some snippets from a class that extends AsyncTask. I want to start a progressDialog in the preExecute() method and do a progressDialog.dismiss(); in the postExecute() method. All the examples I find say to do it like below. The problem I'm having is that dialog is out of scope in onPostExecute. This is expected except but all the examples seem to do it this way. I also noticed that up at the import there's a little warning sign saying that the import is unused. Should this ProgressDialog work? Do I need to pass it around?

```
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
...

protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){//error when doing this in resetDisplay.... onPostExecute is invoked by the ui thread so this may be why it works here and not in resetDisplay
                    ImageView imageView=(ImageView) parent.findViewById(R.id.imageDisplay);
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(image);

                    dialog.dismiss();

                }
protected void onPreExecute(){
                    ProgressDialog dialog=ProgressDialog.show(parent, "Loading", "Loading the image of the day");
                }
```

Comment: i think the problem may be in the reference of the ProgressDialog variable..may be you should use it like in the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339847/how-to-add-progressdialog/11339895#11339895

Comment: [See this tuts...](http://samir-mangroliya.blogspot.in/p/android-asynctask-example.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class YourClass extends AsyncTask<...>
{
    ProgressDialog dialog;
    Protected void onPreExecute(){
        // create dialog here
       dialog= new ProgressDialog (...);
    }
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image){
        //
        dialog.dismiss();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See the below code

```
private class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Boolean> {

    private ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(HomeActivity.this);

    /** progress dialog to show user that the backup is processing. */
    /** application context. */

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        this.dialog.setMessage("Please wait");
        this.dialog.show();
    }

    protected Boolean doInBackground(final String... args) {
        try {

            /**
             * Fetch the RSS Feeds from URL
             */
            Utilities.arrayRSS = objRSSFeed
                    .FetchRSSFeeds(Constants.Feed_URL);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("tag", "error", e);
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Boolean success) {

        if (dialog.isShowing()) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }

        if (success) {
            // display UI
            UpdateDisplay();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the `ProgressDialog dialog` outside the `onPreExecute()`
Declare the dialog in the activity and then use in the preExecute() and postExecute() methods.
Declare like this in teh activity or inside the async task

```
ProgressDialog dialog=new Progress Dialog(YourActivity.this);
```

Then use the dialog in onPreExecute() as

```
 dialog.setMessage("Your Messgae");
 dialog.show();
```

and in onPostExecute() as

```
dialog.dismiss();
```